# Cross-references in eledmac

Tags: cross-referencing, eledmac

When I create an `\edlabel{}` in a critical text made with `eledmac`, the result I get from referencing the label with either `\edpageref`, `\lineref`, `\sublineref` or `\pstartref` don't seem quite intelligble to me.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{eledmac}
\begin{document}

List of references:

Pageref: \xpageref{cicero}

Lineref: \lineref{cicero}

Sublineref: \sublineref{cicero}

pstartref: \pstartref{cicero}


\beginnumbering
\pstart
neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, 
adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et 
dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum 
exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi 
consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse
quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas 
nulla pariatur?\edlabel{cicero}
\pend
\endnumbering

\end{document}
```

This produces the following result on my system:
[image: output of MWE]

I believe that the first 1 (before the dash) refers to the page, since it is 2 if I insert a pagebreak. But none the less, I don't see how either of these would be understandable references to the current label. It is located on line 7 of the text.

What am I doing wrong here?

Additional note: It seems to me that when the labels are not in the same document as the refs (two seperate files included in master document with `\include{}`), the "reference" only has the second part and is formated with a pipe, e.g.: `|1` or `|2` for `\edpageref` and `\lineref` respectively.

Comment: that is a bug in the version 1.10.0. I will correct it now

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that has been updated in a recent version of the software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1.10.3 release, that I have just uploaded on CTAN, fixes this problem. Thanks for your message. See https://github.com/maieul/ledmac/releases/tag/mac1.10.3-par1.6.0 if you want to have the correct version now.